# IconButton.filled() raises not defined error

Tags: flutter, dart, material3

I was playing with the new Material 3 styles in Flutter and got some errors. The code I wanted to test was: [Flutter>material>IconButton class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/IconButton-class.html#material.IconButton.3)
 using IconButton.filled() raised error on my project so I recreated the sample on my PC but still got the same issue. I recreated this code with this command:

```bash
flutter create --sample=material.IconButton.3 mysample
```

Here is code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Flutter code sample for [IconButton].

void main() {
  runApp(const IconButtonApp());
}

class IconButtonApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const IconButtonApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
          colorSchemeSeed: const Color(0xff6750a4), useMaterial3: true),
      title: 'Icon Button Types',
      home: const Scaffold(
        body: ButtonTypesExample(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ButtonTypesExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const ButtonTypesExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
      child: Row( // Here I get different Error (Error 1). (not sure if this relates to this issue)
        children: <Widget>[
          Spacer(),
          ButtonTypesGroup(enabled: true),
          ButtonTypesGroup(enabled: false),
          Spacer(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ButtonTypesGroup extends StatelessWidget {
  const ButtonTypesGroup({super.key, required this.enabled});

  final bool enabled;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final VoidCallback? onPressed = enabled ? () {} : null;

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.filter_drama), onPressed: onPressed),

          // Filled icon button
          IconButton.filled( // Error (Error 2)
              onPressed: onPressed, icon: const Icon(Icons.filter_drama)),

          // Filled tonal icon button
          IconButton.filledTonal( // Error (Error 2)
              onPressed: onPressed, icon: const Icon(Icons.filter_drama)),

          // Outlined icon button
          IconButton.outlined( // Error (Error 2)
              onPressed: onPressed, icon: const Icon(Icons.filter_drama)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Error 1: The constructor being called isn't a const constructor.
Try removing 'const' from the constructor invocation.dart(const_with_non_const)

Error 2: The method 'filled' isn't defined for the type 'IconButton'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'filled'.dart(undefined_method)

pubspec.yaml:

```yaml
name: mysample
description: A new Flutter project.
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.19.6 <3.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.10, on macOS 13.3.1 22E772610a
    darwin-arm64, locale en-JP)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
    33.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.78.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IconButton.filled` was added in flutter 3.10, so it's not available in the 3.7.10 version that you have. Simply write

```
flutter upgrade
```

to get the latest version and it should remove the errors